# Identifying rings (or in general algebraic structures) modulo isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be subrings of a ring $R$. Suppose that $A'$ and $B'$ are subrings of $R$ such that $A' \subseteq A$ and  $B' \subseteq B$ and $A'\simeq B'$ are isomorphic.

Can i ALWAYS suppose that $A'=B'=:C$ and say that $C \subseteq A\cap B\subseteq R$  ? (i.e. indentify $A'$ and $B'$ and consider it as a common subring of $A$ and $B$). Even if i know that $A$ and $B$ don't have common subrings exept for the subring generated by $\{0,1\}$?

Or there are cases in which this identification leads to "errors"?

In algebraic geometry one often choose an "ambient" algebraic structure (say ring) in which submerge other rings by monomorphisms and assume that they are all subrings of this one "ambient"; and if some rings $A_1,\dots, A_n$ have subrings isomorphic, one identify them into one and consider it as as common subring of  $A_1,\dots, A_n$. Is always "risk free" this procedure? Or there are some hidden warnings?

Comment: How would this work with $R=\Bbb C$, $A=A'=\Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]2]$, $B=B'=\Bbb Q\left[\sqrt[3]2\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\right]$ ?
In this case, $A'\cong B'\cong\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{(x^3-2)}$, and $A\cap B=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Let $R$ be an integral domain, let Quot$R$ be the field of fractions of $R$. I know that if $M$ is a maximal ideal in $R$, i can consider $R$ as subring of the localization $R_M$. My book says that i can assume that $R\subseteq \bigcap R_M \subseteq $ Quot$R$. So, why in this case is it possibile?


I know that each $R_M$ has a subring isomorphic to $R$, so i assume it is $R$.


What's the difference between this case and my question?

Comment: Because there are embeddings $i_M: R\to R_M$, $i:R\to Quot R$, $e_M: R_M \to Quot R$ such that $e_M\circ i_M = i$. These things often come with practice and you know when some identification of this sort can be done; but if you're not comfortable with it yet, you can always prove that this is something you can assume (or see why it's not); or just not identify anything and use the different embeddings you have at your disposal, at the risk of having notational issues